# Image not showing in body after append (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is something like this

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
    $(this).find('img').addClass(".gray");
    var imgs = `<div id="preview"> <img src="images/medium/${$(this).find('img').attr('id')}"
                alt="${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}"/></div>`;
    var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('city')}
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('taken')};
                </p>`;
    // imgs += info;
    $("body").append($(imgs));
    console.log(imgs);
})
```

I'm using CSS class to define position

```
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    $("#preview").css("left", event.pageX);
    $("#preview").css("top", event.pageY);
});
```

```
#preview {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #424242;
}
.gray {
     filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

I have checked image paths, they are correct.

I want to popup an image when mouse is hovered. I'm able to seeing events being reported correctly in console but nothing happens on the front side page.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. The JS looks fine in isolation. I would assume the path to the img src is wrong, as you only provide the `id` with no file extension, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I've added some additional info. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: To help you we need to see a working example including all relevant HTML, CSS and JS. Use the snippet tool within the question editor to add this info

Comment: Added the CSS parts also. I think this info is the relevant. Remaining portion of the code is working as expected and are not dependent on this.

Comment: The HTML is the most relevant, which you still haven't added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the CSS. You have `#preview {display: none}`, which is hiding the parent div of the image. If you remove `display: none`, then it should show.

Also, you don't have to include the `.` when adding a class:

```
$(this).find('img').addClass("gray") // Note that there is no '.'
```

Comment: @kl_divergence Hmmm... I think it might be because it's appending the HTML `<img>` as a string and not as an element. I'll do a quick test and see what I can find and update the answer =)

Comment: Actually @kl_divergence , it's the CSS. You have `#preview {display: none}`, which is hiding the parent div of the image.

Comment: Oh, yeah, didn't check this setting. Thanks